# Problem setting up view model adapter during inflate XML

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a MainFragment.kt

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.FragmentMainBinding


private const val TAG = "MainFragmentXX"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the default destination in the navigation.
 */
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskTimerViewModel::class.java] } // New
    private val mAdapter = CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(null) // null=view with instructions NEW

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val funct = "onCreate"
        Log.d(TAG, funct)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "$funct about to register viewModel")
        viewModel.cursor.observe( // New
            this, Observer { cursor -> mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)?.close() }
        )
        Log.d(TAG, "$funct done")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView")
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated")
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.taskList.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context) // Set layout manager to Linear NEW
        binding.taskList.adapter = mAdapter // Attach Adapter to Recyclerview New
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView")
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    // ** From here ist just logging functions **

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach")
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

//    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { // depreciated
//        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated(depreciated)")
//        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
//    }


    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored")
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState")
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop")
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDetach")
        super.onDetach()
    }
}
```

And am getting the following errors in Logcat when

```
viewModel.cursor.observe( // New
  this, Observer { cursor -> mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)?.close() }
)
```

runs in onCreate (i.e. if I comment out this it works)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.funkytwig.takstimer, PID: 7099
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.funkytwig.takstimer/com.funkytwig.tasktimer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.funkytwig.takstimer:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.funkytwig.takstimer:layout/content_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.funkytwig.takstimer:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.funkytwig.takstimer:layout/content_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.funkytwig.takstimer:layout/content_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.funkytwig.tasktimer.TaskTimerViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:320)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.MainFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(MainFragment.kt:23)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.MainFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(MainFragment.kt:23)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.MainFragment.getViewModel(MainFragment.kt:23)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.MainFragment.onCreate(MainFragment.kt:35)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1720)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.kt:158)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:53)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:55)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:49)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:312)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:215)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:169)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:203)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:515)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:392)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.AppProvider.query(AppProvider.kt:125)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1214)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1307)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:267)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.TaskTimerViewModel.loadTasks(TaskTimerViewModel.kt:32)
    at com.funkytwig.tasktimer.TaskTimerViewModel.<init>(TaskTimerViewModel.kt:19)
    ... 53 more
```

TaskTimerViewModel.kt is

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.app.Application
import android.database.Cursor
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData

private const val TAG = "TaskTimerViewModelXX"

class TaskTimerViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val dbCursor = MutableLiveData<Cursor>()
    val cursor: LiveData<Cursor>
        get() = dbCursor

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "init")
        loadTasks()
    }

    private fun loadTasks() {
        val funct = "loadTasks"
        Log.d(TAG, funct)
        val projection = arrayOf(
            TasksContract.Columns.TASK_NAME,
            TasksContract.Columns.TASK_DESCRIPTION,
            TasksContract.Columns.TASK_SORT_ORDER
        )
        val sortOrder =
            "${TasksContract.Columns.TASK_SORT_ORDER}, ${TasksContract.Columns.TASK_NAME}"
        val cursor = getApplication<Application>().contentResolver.query(
            TasksContract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, projection, sortOrder
        )
        dbCursor.postValue(cursor!!) // Update on different thread
        Log.d(TAG, "$funct done")

    }
}
```

CursorViewRecyclerAdapter.kt is

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.database.Cursor
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.TaskListItemsBinding

private const val TAG = "CurRecViewAdapterXX"

class TaskViewHolder(private val binding: TaskListItemsBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val taskListName: TextView = binding.taskListName
    val taskListDescription: TextView = binding.taskListDescription
    val taskListEdit: ImageButton = binding.taskListEdit
    val taskListDelete: ImageButton = binding.taskListDelete
}

class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(private var cursor: Cursor?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskViewHolder>() {

    // Called by Recyclerview when it needs new view to display
    // viewType allows different types to be shows on different lines of view,
    // to find out more google 'Recyclerview getItemViewType
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder (new view requested)")
        val viewHolder = TaskListItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return TaskViewHolder(viewHolder)
    }

    // When Recycler view wants new data to be displayed and is providing existing view to be reused
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val func = "onBindViewHolder"
        Log.d(TAG, "$func (bind data to view)")

        val cursor = cursor // Smart Cast Hack

        if (cursor == null || cursor.count == 0) { // No items in cursor

            Log.d(TAG, "$func: providing instructions ")
            holder.taskListName.setText(R.string.instructions_heading)
            holder.taskListDescription.setText(R.string.instructions)
            holder.taskListEdit.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.taskListDelete.visibility = View.GONE

        } else { // Cursor not empty

            if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) throw IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position $position")
            // Create Task object from data in cursor

            val task = Task(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.TASK_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.TASK_DESCRIPTION)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.TASK_SORT_ORDER))
            )
            // Remember ID is not set in constructor
            task.id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.ID))

            holder.taskListName.text = task.name
            holder.taskListDescription.text = task.description
            holder.taskListEdit.visibility = View.VISIBLE // TODO: add onclick
            holder.taskListDelete.visibility = View.VISIBLE // TODO: add onclick
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        val func = "getItemCount"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        val count = cursor?.count
        if (count == 0 || cursor == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: no items so return 1")
            return 1 // So Instructions are displayed if cursor empty
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: $count items")
            return count!!.toInt()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap is a new cursor, returning the old cursor.
     * The returned cursor is *not* closed
     *
     * This allows underlying cursor to be swapped if data changes and we need to re query
     * Should be called when the cursor that the adapter is using is changed.
     * Reruns previous cursor so it can be closed.
     *
     * @param newCursor The new cursor to be used if there was not one.
     * If the given new cursor is the same as the previous set cursor, null is also returned.
     */
    fun swapCursor(newCursor: Cursor?): Cursor? {
        if (newCursor === cursor) return null

        val numItems = itemCount
        val oldCursor = cursor

        if (newCursor != null) {
            // notify observer about cursor
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else { // cursor has changed
            // Notify observer about lack of dataset, all of it from 0 to newItems,
            // i.e. whole range of records has gone
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, numItems)
        }

        return oldCursor
    }
}
```

All the code is at https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer/tree/master/app/src/main

Ive been googling and trying to work this out for a few houres but no joy.

Comment: Your problem lies in `com.funkytwig.tasktimer.AppProvider`, in your `query()` function, where your SQL and bind parameters do not match: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.`.

Comment: Thanks, I was passing arguments in the wrong order to the Resolver, I was passing null to the projection.